# Prime ng file upload won't work

Tags: angular, primeng

Im trying to implement to make a file upload. But i'm getting this error. *Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN*. I don't know how to fix it. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: csrf token are set by server to prevent CSRF attack. What server framework are you using? Look at its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the `onBeforeUpload`

> Callback to invoke before file upload begins to customize the request such as post parameters before the files.

and `onBeforeSend`

> Callback to invoke before file send begins to customize the request such as adding headers.

callbacks respectively to modify the XmlHttpRequest to your needs.

See [the documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload) for event parameters.